# How to scan the whole disk in Linux using c?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

In my application ,I need full disk scan to find elf files and executable files recursively . How to solve the problem in Linux c ?

Comment: look here http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/scandir.3.html

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use the standard `find` program, then use the POSIX [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) function (or possibly the
[`ftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftw.html) function) to traverse the hierarchy and write a suitable visitor function.

The first 4 bytes of an ELF file are:

```
0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46
 DEL    E    L    F
```

what follows is platform and version specific.

For example, `file` reports:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

and the output of the first 16 bytes of hex is:

```
0x0000: 7F 45 4C 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   .ELF............
```

This differs slightly from the output shown by [Mahonri Moriancumer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3525545/mahonri-moriancumer) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23053156/15168) after the first 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks . ftw() is very suitable .

Answer (score 0):

1. Start at the root of the filesystem.
2. Scan the directory using opendir() readdir() closedir().
3. For each entry:

   1. detect elf files by their file *"magic",
   2. detect sub-directory entries via (struct dirent *)->d_type.
4. When a sub-directory is encountered, recurse to 2 above.

*ELF file magic(file offset 0):

```
 7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: Would you care to run `file` on one of the object or executable files that generates the ELF string you show for comparison with the string that is generated on 64-bit Intel (x86_64) ELF.  The first 4 bytes are the magic number; the remaining 12 bytes of the first 16 encode 32-bit vs 64-bit, LSB vs MSB (endianness), version, type, etc.  I believe you're info encodes 32-bit (01) MSB (big endian), version 1 (01), SYSV (00).  Other information comes later in the header.